# Make [andrdoid] a synonym of [android]

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

I think [andrdoid](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/andrdoid) is a misspelling of [android](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android). The one question tagged [andrdoid](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/andrdoid) appears to be about [android](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android). [andrdoid](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/andrdoid) should be made a synonym of [android](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Great catch!  Thank you David!

I've retagged the question you found to be tagged as [android](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android) instead of the misspelling.

I also removed the erroneously spelled tag.

Thank you again!